# How to duplicate category name

Tags: php, oop

I want to make a input box where first check duplicate category. If it find a duplicate category then it return `false` but if it don't find duplicate then insert new category name into database.

It check duplicate properly and insert category properly but show this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to 
string in C:\wamp\www\ecommerce\class\category.php on line 23

Call Stack

# Time   Memory Function              Location
1 0.0006 137488 {main}()              ..\catadd.php:0
2 0.0146 176512 Category->insertCat() ..\catadd.php:15
```

**Here is the method that causes the error:**

```
public function insertCat($catName)
{
    $catName = $this->fm->validation($catName);
    $catName = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $catName);
    if(empty($catName)){
        $msg = 'Cat name can not empty';
        return $msg;
    }else{
        $dcatName = "select * from tbl_category where catName='$catName'";
        $rowCount = $this->db->select($dcatName);
        $catRow = mysqli_num_rows($rowCount);
        if( $catRow > 0 ){              /* <---- Line 23 ----- */
            echo 'Cat Name already Exist';
        }else{
            $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_category (catName) VALUES ('$catName')";
            $catResult= $this->db->insert($query);
            if($catResult){
                $msg = 'Cat name Updated';
                return $msg;
                return $msg;
            }else{
                $msg = 'Not updated';
                return $msg;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

The `select` method looks like:

```
// Select or Read data 
public function select($query){ 
    $result = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__); 
    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        return $result; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

On compilation, I got this warning:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\ecommerce\class\category.php on line 22 ( $catRow = mysqli_num_rows($rowCount); is line 22)

Comment: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\ecommerce\class\category.php on line 22  ( $catRow = mysqli_num_rows($rowCount);  is line 22)

Comment: What is line `23`?

Comment: if( $catRow > 0 ){
    echo 'Cat Name already Exist';
   }else{
    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_category (catName) VALUES ('$catName')";
    $catResult= $this->db->insert($query);
    if($catResult){
    $msg = 'Cat name Updated';
    return $msg;
    return $msg;
    }else{
     $msg = 'Not updated';
     return $msg;
    }
   }

Comment: @Student `$this->db->select` most likely returned false because the query failed.

Comment: @Student how does the select method look?

Comment: // Select or Read data
public function select($query){
  $result = $this->link->query($query) or  die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
  if($result->num_rows > 0){
    return $result;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
 }

Comment: Formatting, added comment code answer in question

Answer (score 1):

Considering your `select` method looks like this:

```
public function select($query)
    {
        $result = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            return $result;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

...this method already checks number of rows so this row:

```
 $catRow = mysqli_num_rows($rowCount);
```

...is not needed, furthermore, causes an error if the `select()` method returns no rows, it returns `false` which will produce the error when you try to reference a method from a `false` return. You should be able to just do:

```
# This will either return the resource or false so you don't need
# to count rows
$rowCount = $this->db->select($dcatName);
if($rowCount) {
```

**EDIT:**

One point I should make is that you should probably modify your `select()` method (and any other query methods you have) to accept an array as a second parameter. That second array should let the method know that you need to `bind_param` so you can use that feature. This may be an SQL Injection vulnerability:

```
$dcatName = "select * from tbl_category where catName='$catName'";
```